# Can not log into SharePoint

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-foundation, active-directory, login

I have a SP 2010 Cluster all set up. Its running AD (Active Directory) for authentication and I can login just fine. I need to create a new user account, so I had the window's AD guys create the account, we verified that this new account can log into the domain. I then hopped into SP2010 and it pulled up the user as expected and I granted the user permissions view the site (I just used a generic view permissions group). However when the user tries to log into SP2010 with the account, they can't get in. I tried changing the permission group around, but nothing seems to work.

The user is just stuck at the opening login with the standard windows popup. We have made sure the user is in the correct domain. So I'm thinking the issue is that I missed something in SharePoint, since I'm admittedly new to SP2010 Administration.

Any ideas???

Comment: Are you only having issues with this user account? Do other accounts work on the same workstation?

Comment: Yes other accounts were able to log in normally. I was also able to take existing employees, grant them permissions into SharePoint, and they could log in normally. The issue was just with this newly created user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen that happen lots of times. It's not a Sharepoint problem. Add your sharepoint site to Trusted Sites or Intranet sites on Internet Explorer. That should take care of it. I'd suggest you add a Active Directory Group Policy to do this for all users.

Comment: Thanks, turns out it was an Active Directory group that was locking me out. I'm all set now!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an issue related to Active Directory, however it didn't have anything to do with "trusted sites". Once we got the user added to the right group it fixed the problem. I'm going to "untangle" our SharePoint authentication and see if I can provide some more information. In the mean time I hope this helps others with the same issue.